# how to hide an item from gridView, Without remaining empty space

Tags: android, gridview

hello mates hope you having a nice day,i have an asyncTask that fills Up my gridView's getItem()
.
.
.

```
    } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

         new ItemFiller(tempCache, convertView, holder.date, holder.iv, holder.username, holder.company, holder.lmcp, holder.details, holder.category, holder.phone, currentCat, position).execute();

        return convertView;
```

but in some conditions that will be investigated in the asynctask, i need the item to be totally hidden or be removed from my gridview, so i tried to use

```
convertView.setVisibilty(View.GONE)
```

item is hidden but its empty remnant is still there, here is my gridview

```
  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/jobstlist_grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="150dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

is there any propery way to do what i need? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this issue as below.
While overriding getView i am setting setTag() with my item name and in onItemClickListener, insteadOf checking with position i am checking with view.getTag(). check sample as below.

```
public View getView(int position,View view, ViewGroup parent){
view.setTag("itemName");
}


onItemClickListener(AapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
switch(view.getTag()){
case "itemName":
break;
}
}
```